# Subtract a predefined value from pandas dataframe column number and return new number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of shape (3000,60630).I am working on a binary classification problem.There are 12126 pad details each of which represent a feature of pad.

```
    First 12126 columns-feature 1
    2nd 12126 columns-feature 2
    3rd 12126 columns-feature 3
    4th 12126 columns-feature 4
    5th 12126 columns feature 5

In total 60630 columns.
```

For the sake of simplicity in building ML model i have given column numbers from 1 to 60630.But now I need to retrieve the original pad details.

AFter each 12126 columns,I need to start again at 1.I dont want to make change in my original dataframe.For reporting purpose I need those details.

```
 Eg:12127 corresponds to pad1
60630 corresponds to pad 12126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(3, 60630)))

In [6]: df.columns
Out[6]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=60630, step=1)

In [7]: i = 0

In [8]: df.iloc[:, 12126*i:12126*(i+1)].columns
Out[8]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=12126, step=1)

In [9]: i = 1

In [10]: df.iloc[:, 12126*i:12126*(i+1)].columns
Out[10]: RangeIndex(start=12126, stop=24252, step=1)
```